# RunningObjectTable access in Windows Store App

Tags: com, windows-store-apps, com-interop, windows-rt

We have an requirement to integrate our WPF application and Windows Store app with some very old COM technology.

It requires us hosting a 3rd party web site in a browser control. That page does a GetObject call in VBScript to find a COM component that we will have had to add to the RunningObjectTable (ROT).

The 3rd party web site cannot be changed any time soon. This works currently in old VC++ app.

I am currently having and issue with the WPF app but will deal with that in a separate question.

I am guessing what we are considering doing is not going to work in a Windows Store app. I was hoping someone can confirm what I believe

1. The WebView control in Windows Store will not support VBScript running within it
2. A Windows Store app cannot target a .NET Framework dll (*Rather that NETCore) that is a wrapper around a COM interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A store app would be using the EdgeHTML engine to host web pages, which has no VBScript support.

A store app would be using the appcontainer integrity level ROT, which is different than the medium integrity level ROT accessible from your old VC++ app (forget .Net wrapper of COM server if the COM server itself won't work).